Как вообще реализовывается доступ к закрытому api?
Например, есть биржа kwork с фриланс заказами. У нее закрытый api, но существуют модулю, имеющие доступ к этому api. Вот, например: https://github.com/kesha1225/pykwork
Как это возможно вообще? Есть какие-то библиотеки, получающие доступ к закрытому api? Смысл тогда делать api закрытым, если все, кому не лень каким-то образом подключаются туда. Там вроде пароли,токены нужны. А тут просто подключаешься. Если кто-то знает объясните пожалуйста, спасибо!

Значит api на самом деле не закрытый

Если на github есть проект, который использует API,но к этому API нельзя подключится напрямую,то ,возможно, оно использует некоторую систему аутентификации (токены или API ключи). В случае с тем репозиторием, что вы прикрепили выше, видно, что в каждом запросе в заголовки прокидывается заголовок с авторизацией, который содержит в себе некий токен (прикрепил фото).

